# Asking for overwrite while trying to run script in ipython

Tags: python, import, module, ipython

I am fairly new to programming in python.  I installed anaconda and am running iPython (the Jupyter qtconsole) v.4.3.0 and python v.3.6 on a Mac.  Currently, I am trying to import a module with functions located in my home directory.

I have looked at stackoverflow and python documentation and found that it could be done with:

```
%run "Users/myUser/python_functions.py"
```

or

```
import python_functions
```

However, when I try both of these approaches, I get prompted to overwrite the file that I am running or importing:

```
File `python_functions.py` exists. Overwrite (y/[N])?
```

This is changing the previous file and not getting the functions I want to be imported.

What may explain this, and what can I do to import my module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Jupyter qtconsole as an interpreter is likely causing the problem in this scenario.  Instead using a IDE or command line interpreter will resolve it .

Since anaconda was installed, trying it with the IDE Spyder executes the code just fine without the overwrite prompt.  It works on others (e.g PyCharm, Rodeo, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is **wrong** but leaving it up for shame

`import` on ubuntu (and I'm guessing many other unix-like OSs including Mac) is a utility that `saves any visible window on an X server and outputs it as an image file. You can capture a single window, the entire screen, or any rectangular portion of the screen.`

My guess if you are running the import command in your console, and it's about to take a screenshot and save it over an existing file - `python_functions`

Before you the use the `python` import command, start a python interpreter:

```
$ python
>>>import yourfile
```

edit: on re-reading your question, I'm not so sure about my guess anymore, but leaving it up until you tell me I'm wrong :)

Comment: If jupyter qtconsole is not an interpreter, how do I get to that on anaconda?

Comment: I guessed you where outside the python interpreter, because it would never overwrite when you run import. But my guess is way off.

Comment: try just running the python interpreter and see if it works?

Comment: right, you're fine.  That works in the commandline, but I think I misunderstood what the qtconsole that comes with anaconda is used for.  I suppose it itself is not a python interpreter and I would need to install an IDE like Pycharm or use the commandline in order to import.   Correct?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd definitely recommend trying Pycharm. A lot of people rag on it but as a tool to help learn python fluency, it's fantastic.